# Python blob PDF stored in Microsoft SQL - convert back to PDF

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pdf, blob

I have a PDF document stored as a Blob in a Microsoft SQL database.  I am trying to convert the blob back to PDF to open in memory for analysis and also possibly save it to a local drive.  I tried saving one of the documents using ".read" but it gives me an error:

> ValueError: embedded null byte

Here is my code/attempt:

```
connect = pyodbc.connect(
Driver = driver,
Server = server,
Database = database,
User = username,
Password = password)

test_query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM test.PDFs"

df_test = pd.read_sql(test_query, connect)

df_test_pdf = df_test['RawDocument'][0]

with open(df_test_pdf, "rb") as f:
   b = f.read

print(df_test_pdf)
```

Comment: `open` is meant to open *files*. `df_test_pdf` though isn't a file. At best, it's a buffer in memory. *Save* it to disk first to ensure you can read it.

Comment: Okay, the PDF blob is in the 'RawDocument' column, how do i avoid creating a buffer in memory and saving the fie?  When I try writing it I get this error:

    




    
     df_test_pdf = df_test_pdf.write(df_test_pdf)

"AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'write'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with this

```
with open("Output.pdf", "wb") as output_file:
    cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 RawDocument FROM test.PDFs")
    ablob = cursor.fetchone()
    output_file.write(ablob[0])
```

Got the answer from a similar question here:

[Writing blob from SQLite to file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379166/writing-blob-from-sqlite-to-file-using-python)